# How to change sendSynchronousRequest to sendASynchronousRequest in ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services, ios5

I am uploading image on server.
how to change Synchronous request to ASynchronous request. because i wanna use progressbar while uploading image..

My code is.

```
+(NSDictionary *)UploadPhoto :(UIImage *)image{

    NSString *DeviceId;
    NSString *TokenValue=tokenTemp;

    DeviceId = DevID;

    NSString *Nonce=[self generateRandomString];
    NSString *currentTimeStamp = [self GetTimeStamp];


    NSString *Cipher=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@",mySecret,DeviceId,Nonce,currentTimeStamp,TokenValue];
    Cipher=[Cipher URLDecodedString];
    Cipher=[self GetCipher:Cipher];
    UIImage *TempPicture=image;//[UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    NSData *PictureData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(TempPicture, 1.0);
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Messages.php",WebServiceUrl]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:20.0f];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=*****" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
    NSString *stringBoundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"*****"];

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"method\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Upload"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Type\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"0"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Name\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"XYZ ****************"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"MessageImage\"; filename=\"c.png\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:PictureData]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody: postBody];

    [request setValue:Cipher forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cipher"];
    [request setValue:DeviceId forHTTPHeaderField:@"Deviceid"];
    [request setValue:Nonce forHTTPHeaderField:@"Nonce"];
    [request setValue:currentTimeStamp forHTTPHeaderField:@"Timestamp"];
    [request setValue:TokenValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Token"];

    [request setHTTPBody:postBody];
    NSError *error;
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if (!data) {
          NSLog(@"nil");
    }
    NSDictionary *temp= [response allHeaderFields];

    NSString *temp2= [temp objectForKey:@"Responsecode"];
    if(temp2!=nil && [temp2 length]>0)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
    return temp;
}
```

Thanks.. 
please help..

how to call 
`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite`  in this code..

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem? You just use [sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and handle the response stuff in the `completionHandler` block.

Comment: NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: blocks the current thread until it completes. and we cant use progress bar while uploading in sendSynchronousRequest method.. and i wanna show total file size and downloading file size.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to want to track the upload progress, you have to use

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]
```

and implement all the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods. This is described [in this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE).

In particular the `connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:` delegate methods informs you about the upload progress.

Another advantage of this method is that you can *cancel* a request, which is not possible with `sendSynchronousRequest` or `sendASynchronousRequest`.

Comment: Please read the "Using NSURLConnection" documentation first and try to implement that. If it does not work, you can ask concrete questions.